# Local variables named after keywords

Tags: python, keyword, local-variables

It's a bit late to ask on my end, given that it's some overdue school project, but I thought I had something going on when I went about programming my little dungeon game code with flavor text and names for the monsters and so on. Suddenly, when I went about trying to run the code and move upstairs, I got hit with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 220, in <module>
  File "python", line 199, in Options
  File "python", line 115, in Movement
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not entirely sure how I managed to make a local variable out of a keyword, although I suppose it being inside of a custom function is what's throwing it all out of wack.
The code in question goes as such:

```py
def Movement():
  #move in cardinal directions, wherever possible
  #input is the direction you want to go
  #output is the ensuing change in position, whether it be vertical or horizontal
  global Position
  global Room
  direction=str(input("Where do you want to go?"))
  if direction=='up' or direction=='Up' or direction=='UP':
    if 'staircase up' in Position:
      Floor +=1
    else:
print("You wish you could climb the walls, but you need some stairs to go up for now.")
    if 'staircase down' in Position:
      Floor -=1
    else:
print:("You could jump out a window, but that'd probably be lethal; best to stick with stairs for now.")
  if (direction=='left' or direction=='Left' or direction=='LEFT') and Room>0 and not(('ANGRY HOG' or 
'BLIND DRAGON') in Position):
    Room -=1
    Room +=1
  else:
    print("That's not going to work.")
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you, but the indentation looks like it must be wrong - you'll have to correct that yourself, since you're the one who knows how it should be indented. You can edit the question to do so.

Comment: Python won’t warn you if you use a statement like `print=1`, or define your own `print()` function. Also, which line of the code in the question is giving the error?

Comment: The `print:(` part is definitely wrong, there shouldn't be a colon there, but I'm not sure if that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah that’s because the question doesn’t actually say which line of code gives the error

Comment: I think it is this line here: `print:("You could jump out a window, but that'd probably be lethal; best to stick with stairs for now.")` Remove the colon between print and the bracket

Comment: I haven't the sharpest eyes, so the whole colon thing might have been what threw me off, haha

Comment: It works! a   bit further along the line
I guess now the issue's just having to comb through the rest of the code to see if there's any other sort of syntax I've royally messed up, yeah?
Thanks again! You guys respond crazy fast haha

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
print:("You could jump out a window <...>")
```

[Annotates](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) the local variable `print` to be of type `"You could jump out a window <...>"`. After this statement, the interpreter treats `print` as a local variable, and it complains when you later attempt to use it without having assigned a value with the `UnboundedLocalError` that you are experiening.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's parsed as a type annotation. I was wondering how the colon could cause it to be a local variable...